# I got this error from conseil js TezosNodeWriter.sendContractOriginationOperation. What could be the problem

Tags: smart-contracts, deploy, conseiljs

```
Failed to parse the request body: No case matched:
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of endorsement
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of seed_nonce_revelation
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of double_endorsement_evidence
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of double_baking_evidence
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of activate_account
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of proposals
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of ballot
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of reveal
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of transaction
  At /script/storage, no case matched:
    Missing object field int
    Missing object field string
    Missing object field bytes
    Unexpected object instead of array
    At /args[1], no case matched:
      Missing object field int
      Missing object field string
      Missing object field bytes
      Unexpected object instead of array
      At /args[0], no case matched:
        Missing object field int
        Missing object field string
        At /bytes:
          Unhandled error (Invalid_argument "Hex.to_char: 120 is an invalid char")
        Unexpected object instead of array
        Missing object field prim
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of delegation
```

Comment: could you please post the actual query ?